# Adding a rectangle to an existing javascript visualization

Tags: javascript, aladin

I'm trying to add a fixed-size rectangle to an existing javascript visualization (`ipyaladin`). The size of the rectangle is determined by the number of pixels rather than astronomical coordinates (RA/DEC).

One option is to explicitly calculate RA/DEC from pixel values of the rectangle boundaries and then plot them. However, this seems a bit inefficient, since the display itself is already in pixels and it should be possible to overlay a rectangle using pixel values directly (potentially using javascript outside of the `aladin` library).

Here's a code that works (it can be interactively changed via [this link](http://aladin.cds.unistra.fr/AladinLite/doc/API/examples/footprints/)):

```js
var aladin;
A.init.then(() => {
    aladin = A.aladin('#aladin-lite-div', {target: 'M 1', fov: 0.2});

    var overlay = A.graphicOverlay({color: '#ee2345', lineWidth: 3});
    aladin.addOverlay(overlay);
    var poly = A.polygon([[83.64287, 22.01713], [83.59872, 22.01692], [83.59852, 21.97629], [83.64295, 21.97629]]);
    overlay.addFootprints([poly]);
});
```

What I would like to do is define the rectangle boundary using specific number of pixels (height/width), rather than the RA/DEC values.